# Evernote hide list bar

Tags: evernote

I want to use Evernote to take notes & read pdf side by side on my screen (I use Mac).

I remember that OneNote can be minimised properly to be just a side bar on the screen so that I can use the majority of my screen on reading.

However, when in Evernote it seems the "Notes List" bar can never disappear and it's taking around 1/3 of my screen (which is totally a waste when I'm trying to read PDF&take notes on my 13inch MBP)

Is there a way to hide the "Notes List" bar?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle "Show Left Panel" and "Show Note List" options in View menu.

Alternatively, you can double-click on a note in the note list to open it in a new window, and then hide the main Evernote window.

Answer (score 0):

F10 - show/hide notebooks list.

F11 - show/hide notes list (for current notebook).